# Can't reach my alternative SMTP port

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, postfix, smtp, port

I can't seem to reach my open SMTP ports.
I opened 587 and 2525, and it shows they're listening:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2525            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::2525                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I also opened my ports in the iptables:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:2525
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:submission
```

But when I telnet from my computer into port 2525 and 587 it just closes instead of showing the welcome message like it does on port 25.

Here's a part of my master.cf

```
smtp inet n - - - - smtpd
submission inet n      -       n       -       -       smtpd
2525      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

A telnet from the machine itself shows the expected welcome message.
It's weird because it used to work just fine...

I appreciate your help :-)

**EDIT**

@MichaelKjörling gave me the idea to check the PLESK firewall so I added this rule:

[image: plesk custom rule]

Still not working though... might have to give it some time or do I have to restart something to trigger it?

**EDIT**

Output of `iptables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
39468   28M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
    2    80 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
  232 13920 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2525
  430 22420 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8880
  943 53740 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
    1    48 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
    4   208 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
   24  1284 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465
   80  3952 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110
    3   192 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143
    1    64 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:106
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5432
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9008
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9080
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:137
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:138
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:139
   18   720 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1194
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
    1    60 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 code 0
    6   289 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
53431   69M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
    2   104 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
  232 13920 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  612 44920 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

**EDIT**

Well apparently the outgoing ports where blocked in where I was testing this from.
Thus I wasn't able to connect, I found this out by connecting to another server with SSH and using telnet from there.

Everything for nothing, thanks for the help!!

Comment: Is there a firewall along the route that may be blocking the connection to the "unusual" ports? Try moving it to something like port 80 and see if it works any better connecting.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I also do suspect a firewall being active but bare in mind that this is a live server, thus I can't move it to port 80 because the webserver is running on that port. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Showing just the rules that permit the traffic you want is useless, because they might never be reached.  Could we get the whole output of `iptables -L -n -v`?

Comment: @MadHatter done and edited as requested, thank you for your help

Comment: The rules seem to in the right order, which makes me wonder if Michael Kjörling has a point.  You could use eg `tcpdump port 587` on the server when you try to telnet to it, to see if the traffic arrives at all.  If it doesn't, that's very strongly suggestive that there's a firewall *en route* causing trouble.

Comment: @MadHatter Nothing arrives, when I use the command on 25 it shows traffic but on port 587 and 2525 it's quiet. What do you suggest I do to find out what's blocking it?

Comment: Talk to your network people.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4110/discussion-between-rick-kuipers-and-madhatter)

Comment: Could you post an answer and mark this question as solved?

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently the outgoing ports where blocked in where I was testing this from. Thus I wasn't able to connect, I found this out by connecting to another server with SSH and using telnet from there.

I appreciated the the help :-)